# How To Change Background Opacity of Charts inside Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sheets

I want to set the transparency or the opacity of the Google Charts in Google Sheets (just like in Microsoft Excel - set the image behind the text so the text still readable)

However it seems the function is not working.
[Preview of the function](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxAiEecsdp72bmJVMk1xUGVnTUk/edit?usp=sharing')

Example [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1az_uTGgcVSPjKURBvYh3QZaZOYu7ocT2cbAqPpEF2r0/edit?usp=sharing) to my document.

I have tried also with the apps script `setBackgroundColor(cssValue)` with `#ffffff` but not working either and found [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3752).

Any solution will be very appreciated.

Comment: Try calling `setBackgroundColor('transparent')`.  The charts support transparent backgrounds in all browsers except IE 8 and older.

Comment: @asgallant I have tried from this documentation [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-pie-chart-builder#setBackgroundColor(String))
However it is not working and it seems this documentation refers to the charts for the UiApp/Script Services not for the Spreadsheet Service.
Or maybe could you help me with my script here
[link](https://script.google.com/macros/d/Md5gedettqqgU1eTh7gPb_6bf99q1XeC3/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvG-erWp-hNEwVSbLAGZCHkIJ6P2VB4kzjGIc4e8RClfS91UteCJiHTZBL6bY0RBI5fp3rcdG0_S8sVLbd16hFdQkBgYcDMklF1pPSUG93gIhhW_ZpPkiTMQNWdEbgDCCyuTt3gI0Q4)

Comment: The Google Docs Spreadsheets give the chart containers a white background, so changing the background of the chart to `transparent` won't allow your data to show through, because the container is blocking it anyway.  I don't know if there is a way to modify the container in your spreadsheet to fix this.

Comment: I just noticed that there id a property for `containerId` to get the ID of the HTML Element that hosts the chart.  [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.drawchart)  I wonder if there is a way to use the DOM to set the container to a different opacity.

Comment: Thank you for all of your responses, now I understand that the problem is in the container. Now I have to learn another way to improve my sheet maybe using the google charts service to get the charts background transparent and embed it into the sheet with 'insert image' function. Anyway, thank you again for your helps

Comment: `.setOption('backgroundColor.fillOpacity',50)`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.setOption('backgroundColor.fillOpacity',50)
```

In the documentation, there is an example of how to modify an existing chart:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("A2:B8")
 var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
 chart = chart.modify()
     .addRange(range)
     .setOption('title', 'Updated!')
     .setOption('animation.duration', 500)
     .setPosition(2,2,0,0)
     .build();
 sheet.updateChart(chart);
```

[Class EmbeddedChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart)

[Class EmbeddedChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder)

[Set Option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#setOption(String,Object))

Before you can change the chart, you need to get a reference it.  There is only one chart in your sheet, so it should be index zero:

```
var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
```

You'll need a way to trigger the function.  I don't know if you want to set that when the spreadsheet loads, or on a user driven event.

Comment: I am able to change the Background Color with the Apps Script, but still I do not know how to make it transparent or semi transparent. What I want to achieve is just to change the transparancy/opacity so I do not need any trigger for this function. Please check my container bound apps script, thanks.
[link](https://script.google.com/macros/d/Md5gedettqqgU1eTh7gPb_6bf99q1XeC3/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvG-erWp-hNEwVSbLAGZCHkIJ6P2VB4kzjGIc4e8RClfS91UteCJiHTZBL6bY0RBI5fp3rcdG0_S8sVLbd16hFdQkBgYcDMklF1pPSUG93gIhhW_ZpPkiTMQNWdEbgDCCyuTt3gI0Q4)

Answer (score 0):

```
function graph() {
  upperLimit = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C123').getValue();
  lowerLimit = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F123').getValue();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('vAxes.0.viewWindow.max', upperLimit)
    .setOption('vAxes.0.viewWindow.min', lowerLimit)
    .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[1];
  chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('backgroundColor',"#00000000")
    .setOption('vAxes.0.viewWindow.max', upperLimit)
    .setOption('vAxes.0.viewWindow.min', lowerLimit)
    .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
};
```

This is what I have done to try to modify an existing chart in google spreadsheet by using app script.
  The first is the scale and the second is the transparent background.
The upper/lower limit is from a calculation result in sheet, capture the data by getValue().
Transparent background is css string #00000000.