# Transparent background of a Google Sheets chart saved as a PNG into Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm having some trouble trying to save a chart into Drive with a transparent background. I can `.setOption('backgroundColor', 'transparent');` but this does not set the background of the "container" the chart is in, so the chart still appears as having a white background.

Does anyone have an idea of how to reference and set the background color of the container the chart is held in?

Thanks
Nick

```html
function saveChartstoGdrive(){
  //Getting chart from the current spreadsheet
  var targetspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = targetspreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sales Graph');
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();         
  var chartBlobs=new Array(charts.length);
  var filePrefix="scrlxz";
  
  //loop through charts saving each to gdrive
  for(var i=0;i<charts.length;i++){
    
    //build each chart
    var builderChart = charts[i].modify();
    builderChart.setOption('width', 1400);
    builderChart.setOption('height', 900);
    builderChart.setOption('title', 'Updated!');
    builderChart.setOption('backgroundColor', 'transparent');
    var newChart =builderChart.build();
  
    //create PNG blob of chart for writing
    chartBlobs[i]= newChart.getAs('image/png');
    
    
    //make sure we have the correct file and prepare for saving
    var fileName = filePrefix+[i]+".png";
    var fileId = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next().getId();
    var contentBlob = chartBlobs[i];
    
    //save file to ggdrive
    var myVar = Drive.Files.update({mimeType: 'image/png'}, fileId, contentBlob);
  }         
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same output if you save the file using `DriveApp.createFile` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob Using the Advanced Drive service can have its challenges at times.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ScottMcC but I need to overwrite the existing file so it's URL and ID does not change, hence the `Drive.Files.update` this has been working fine and I don't think it has any effect on the contents of the PNG.

I can set the background colour to any solid colour and it works fine, and from other posts I can see that `setOption('backgroundColor', 'transparent');` works to set that elements property. Problem is I seem to also need to reference the background of a container the rest of the chart is in.

Comment: I found a few posts that talk about this mythical container  but they are quite old.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948637/how-to-change-background-opacity-of-charts-inside-google-sheets
Unfortunately I can't export the chart as svg otherwise I might be able to work out the structure of it's XML and reference the container.

Comment: Maximize the chart. `.setOption('theme','maximized')`

Comment: or `.setOption('chartArea.backgroundColor','transparent')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I'-'I but they did not work I tried both independantly and together

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to modify the chart on the sheet with the transparent background.
- You want to export the modified chart as a PNG file which has the transparent background.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- Recently, I have reported about [Creating PNG Image with Alpha Channel using Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/Creating-PNG-Image-with-Alpha-Channel-using-Google-Apps-Script). When I saw your question, I thought that this report might be useful. The flow of this report is used for your situation, it becomes as follows.

  1. Retrieve chart and modify chart.
  2. Update chart.
  3. Create new Google Slides as the temporal file.
  4. Change the background color of slide to the transparent.
  5. Insert the modified chart. The background color of chart is the transparent.
  6. Export the slide as PNG with the alpha channel.
  7. The chart is returned back to the original one.
  8. Remove the temporal file.
  9. Create the exported PNG data as a file. In this case, when the file is existing, the file is overwritten. When the file is not found, the file is created as new file.
- And, when I saw your script, the existing chart is modified with the transparent background. So you retrieve the blob from `var newChart =builderChart.build();`. In this case, I found that the modified chart is still not reflected to `newChart`. So, in this modified script, the chart is updated by the modified chart. And, after the updated chart is retrieved, the chart is returned back to the original one.
- And also, in this modified script, when the file of `fileName` is existing, the file is overwritten by new chart. When the file is not found, the file is created using the new chart as new file.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, this script supposes that the sheet "Sales Graph" has the chart. Please be careful this. And, please confirm whether Drive API has already been enabled at Advanced Google services again.

```
function saveChartstoGdrive() {
  var targetspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = targetspreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sales Graph');
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var chartBlobs = new Array(charts.length);
  var filePrefix = "scrlxz";
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    // 1. Retrieve chart and modify chart.
    var orgChart = charts[i]; // Added
    var builderChart = charts[i].modify();
    builderChart.setOption('width', 1400);
    builderChart.setOption('height', 900);
    builderChart.setOption('title', 'Updated!')
    builderChart.setOption('backgroundColor', 'transparent');
    var newChart = builderChart.build();

    // --- I added below script.
    // 2. Update chart.
    sheet.updateChart(newChart); // It seems that this is required to be used for reflecting the settings.

    // 3. Create new Google Slides as the temporal file.
    var temp = SlidesApp.create("temp");
    var slide = temp.getSlides()[0];
    var id = temp.getId();
    slide.getShapes().forEach(s => s.remove());

    // 4. Change the background color of slide to the transparent.
    slide.getBackground().setTransparent();

    // 5. Insert the modified chart. The background color of chart is the transparent.
    slide.insertSheetsChart(newChart);
    temp.saveAndClose();

    // 6. Export the slide as PNG with the alpha channel.
    var url = `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=${id}&exportFormat=png`;
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getBlob();

    // 7. The chart is returned back to the original one.
    sheet.updateChart(orgChart); // Here, the updated chart is returned back to the original one.
    
    // 8. Remove the temporal file.
    DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);

    // --- I modified below script.
    // 9. Create the exported PNG data as a file. In this case, when the file is existing, the file is overwritten. When the file is not found, the file is created as new file.
    chartBlobs[i] = blob;
    var fileName = filePrefix + [i] + ".png";
    var contentBlob = chartBlobs[i];
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
      var fileId = file.next().getId();
      var myVar = Drive.Files.update({ mimeType: 'image/png' }, fileId, contentBlob);
    } else {
      DriveApp.createFile(contentBlob.setName(fileName));
    }
  }
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is run for the following sheet, the PNG file with the alpha channel is obtained.

[image]

In order to confirm the transparent background of PNG file, as a sample, when the created PNG file is inserted to the Spreadsheet, it becomes as follows. You can see that the background of image is transparent.

[image]

#### References:

- [Report: Creating PNG Image with Alpha Channel using Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/Creating-PNG-Image-with-Alpha-Channel-using-Google-Apps-Script)
- [updateChart(chart) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#updatechartchart)
- [insertSheetsChart(sourceChart) of Class Slide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertsheetschartsourcechart)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but i found the simple answer. Just set the background color with an alpha channel:

```
.setOption('backgroundColor', '#00000000')
```